# Regular Expression to anonymize emails

Tags: regex, r

i use in R the regular expression

```
regexp <- "(^|[^([:alnum:]|.|_)])abc@abc.de($|[^[:alnum:]])"
```

to find the email-adress `abc@abc.de` in an spefic text and replace it by an `anonym-mail-adress`.

```
tmp <- c("aaaaabc@abc.debbbb",        ## <- should not be matched
      "aaaa abc@abc.de bbbb",      ## <- should be matched
      "abc@abc.de",                ## <- should be matched
      "aaa.abc@abc.de",            ## <- should not be matched
      "aaaa_abc@abc.de",           ## <- should not be matched
      "(abc@abc.de)",              ## <- should be matched
      "aaaa (abc@abc.de) bbbb")    ## <- should be matched


replacement <- paste("\\1", "anonym@anonym.de", "\\2", sep="")
gsub(regexp, replacement, tmp, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

as result I get

```
> gsub(regexp, replacement, tmp, ignore.case=TRUE)
[1] "aaaaabc@abc.debbbb"         "aaaa anonym@anonym.de bbbb"
[3] "anonym@anonym.de"           "aaa.abc@abc.de"            
[5] "aaaa_abc@abc.de"            "(abc@abc.de)"              
[7] "aaaa (abc.abc.de) bbbb"
```

I don't know why the last two elements of the array are not matched?

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: Is the last string `(abc.abc.de)`  or `(abc@abc.de)`?

Comment: oh sorry, yes the last string is (abc@abc.de), i have corrected this.

Comment: you should probably correct your output as well. But it's minor.

Comment: Not sure if you were looking for an answer. But if you want to find out what's wrong with your expression, [**go here**](http://regex101.com/r/bJ1mU0) to see what's happening.

Comment: please tell me how i could correct my output.

Comment: what do you mean? I've given you an answer. I've given you a link where you could test your regular expression. Have you tried it out?

Comment: i know use your regular expression, the problem with my regular expression was, that it removes whitespace where it shouldn't do that, right?

Comment: please go here: http://regex101.com/r/bJ1mU0 and paste your regular expression and your strings and see the explanation and try changing your pattern to get your results.

Comment: For me it looked like, that you want to say, that i should at my R output, wasn't that right? Of course i went to your link and tried my regular expression. I see very much colors in the explantion, but i must say sorry and don't know the problem....

Comment: I've edited the solution with an explanation of why it doesn't work and what works (by editing your regexp). See if it helps. If so, mark it as "answered" by ticking the check mark to keep it as such for future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
gsub("^(abc@abc)|(?<=[ (])(abc@abc)", "anonym@anonym", tmp, perl=T)
```

The pattern before `|`: `^(abc@abc)` checks for beginning with `abc@abc`, of course.

The pattern after `|` uses `positive lookbehind` and searches for `abc@abc` preceded by `space` or `(` (left paranthesis) and if found, replaces with `anonym@anonym`.

This is what I get: (Note: I replaced `abc.abc` in the last string with `abc@abc`)

```
[1] "aaaaabc@abc.debbbb"           "aaaa anonym@anonym.de bbbb"  
[3] "anonym@anonym.de"             "aaa.abc@abc.de"              
[5] "aaaa_abc@abc.de"              "(anonym@anonym.de)"          
[7] "aaaa (anonym@anonym.de) bbbb"
```

**Edit:** To explain the problem with your regexp, it seems like a problem with the part:

```
[^([:alnum:]|.|_)]
```

I think the negation has to be present in every `|` statement. Also, you should use `[.]` instead of `.` as the latter implies any character. Alternatively, instead of using negation in for every character you're checking, we can condense this part by removing all unncessary `|` as:

```
[^.[:alpha:]_] # not a . or _ or any alphanumeric
# using gsub on it:
gsub("(^|[^.[:alpha:]_])abc@abc", " anonym@anonym", tmp)

# [1] "aaaaabc@abc.debbbb"           "aaaa anonym@anonym.de bbbb"  
# [3] " anonym@anonym.de"            "aaa.abc@abc.de"              
# [5] "aaaa_abc@abc.de"              " anonym@anonym.de)"          
# [7] "aaaa  anonym@anonym.de) bbbb"
```

You get every `abc@abc` replaced. But, you'll lose the character before `abc@abc` everytime because you're checking for it in the pattern as well. So, you'll have to use the capture group. That is, if you wrap a regular expression with `()` then you can refer to that "capture" using special variables such as `\\1, \\2 etc..`. Here, we have captured `(^|[^.[:alpha:]_])`, i.e., the part before `abc@abc`. Since it is the first capture, we'll refer to it as `\\1` to use it to recover the missing character in the previous result:

```
gsub("(^|[^.[:alpha:]_])abc@abc", "\\1anonym@anonym", tmp)

# [1] "aaaaabc@abc.debbbb"           "aaaa anonym@anonym.de bbbb"  
# [3] "anonym@anonym.de"             "aaa.abc@abc.de"              
# [5] "aaaa_abc@abc.de"              "(anonym@anonym.de)"          
# [7] "aaaa (anonym@anonym.de) bbbb"
```

This is the result you needed. And this is the same as my initial answer using positive look-behind. In that case, since it just checks if it is preceded by something, you don't have to capture anything special. Only the `abc@abc` part got replaced. Hope this helps.

Comment: If an approach works for you you can use the check mark below the up down vote (top left side of this solution) to indicate to future users that an answer was the most helpful/solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Now i see another problem with my regular expression instead of "." it should be "\\.", i.e. "abc@abc.de" should not match "aaa.abc@abc.de".

Comment: If you provide it within `[]` as so: `[.]` then you don't have to escape it. But if you provide it like `.abc@abc.de`, then the `.` must be eithe escaped (`\\.`) or `[.]`.

Comment: you can also reduce the first `gsub` even further to: `gsub("(^|(?<=[ (]))(abc@abc)", "anonym@anonym", tmp, perl=T)`